# How to upload two images(not image array) on server with different names using alamofire?

Tags: ios, image, alamofire, image-uploading

I want to upload two images using alamofire...I tried searching it but cant find an accurate answer.Most of the people are doing by creating image array but they are using with same name. I want to do it with different image names

Comment: you can upload 2 images by creating 2 images data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
func uploadImagesAndData(params:[String : AnyObject]?,image1: UIImage,image2: UIImage,image3: UIImage,image4: UIImage,headers : [String : String]?, completionHandler:@escaping CompletionHandler) -> Void {

    let imageData1 = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image1, 0.5)!
    let imageData2 = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image2, 0.5)!

    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in

            for (key, value) in params! {
                if let data = value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) {
                    multipartFormData.append(data, withName: key)
                }
            }

            multipartFormData.append(imageData1, withName: "file1", fileName: "image.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
            multipartFormData.append(imageData2, withName: "file2", fileName: "image.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")

    },
        to: K_BASEURL + K_API_LOGINDATA, encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
            switch encodingResult {
            case .success(let upload, _, _):
                upload
                    .validate()
                    .responseJSON { response in
                        switch response.result {
                        case .success(let value):
                            print("responseObject: \(value)")
                        case .failure(let responseError):
                            print("responseError: \(responseError)")
                        }
                }
            case .failure(let encodingError):
                print("encodingError: \(encodingError)")
            }
    })
```

Comment: @A.Mathur, if you don't mind than accept this answer.